# If no value selected from dropdown, allow textbox to add to mysql table using php, mysql, javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

hi i'm working on triple dropdown for country, state, city using ajax and the reference link is : http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/01/populate-triple-drop-down-list-change-options-value-from-database-using-ajax-and-php.html. It successfully working but i need if a state has no city in db table then a new text box is appear and the entered values is store in php mysql. what coding i'm implement that. please give some ideas.

code:

Ajax:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function getXMLHTTP() {
    var xmlhttp = false;

    try {
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
      try {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      } catch (e) {
        try {
          xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e1) {
          xmlhttp = false;
        }
      }
    }

    return xmlhttp;
  }

  function getState(countryId) {
    var strURL = "findState.php?country=" + countryId;
    var req = getXMLHTTP();

    if (req) {
      req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (req.readyState == 4) {
          // only if "OK"
          if (req.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('statediv').innerHTML = req.responseText;
          } else {
            alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
          }
        }
      }

      req.open("GET", strURL, true);
      req.send(null);
    }
  }

  function getCity(countryId, stateId) {
    var strURL = "findCity.php?country=" + countryId + "&state=" + stateId;
    var req = getXMLHTTP();

    if (req) {
      req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (req.readyState == 4) {
          // only if "OK"
          if (req.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('citydiv').innerHTML = req.responseText;
          } else {
            alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
          }
        }
      }

      req.open("GET", strURL, true);
      req.send(null);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Form:

```
<form method="post" action="" name="form1">
<table width="60%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="150">Country</td>
    <td  width="150"><select name="country" onChange="getState(this.value)">
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
    <option value="1">USA</option>
    <option value="2">Canada</option>
        </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="">
    <td>State</td>
    <td ><div id="statediv"><select name="state" >
    <option>Select Country First</option>
        </select></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="">
    <td>City</td>
    <td ><div id="citydiv"><select name="city">
    <option>Select State First</option>
        </select></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

findstate.php

```
<?php
  include('config.php');
  $country = intval($_GET['country']);
  $query = "SELECT id,statename FROM state WHERE countryid='$country'";
  $result = mysql_query($query);
?>

<select name="state" onchange="getCity(<?php echo $country?>,this.value)">
  <option>Select State</option>
  <?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
    <option value=<?php echo $row['id']?>><?php echo $row['statename']?></option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```

findcity.php

```
<?php
  include('config.php');
  $countryId = intval($_GET['country']);
  $stateId = intval($_GET['state']);
  $query = "SELECT id,city FROM city WHERE  stateid='$stateId'";
  $result = mysql_query($query);
?>

<select name="city">
  <option>Select City</option>
  <?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
    <option value><?php echo $row['city']?></option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```

I want to show if there is no city in any state then a textbox will appear and it's value store to db.

Answer (score 5):

Put this inside **`findcity.php`** file

```
<?php
include('config.php');
$countryId=intval($_GET['country']);
$stateId=intval($_GET['state']);
$query="SELECT id,city FROM city WHERE  stateid='$stateId'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) // no cities found
{
  echo '<input type="textbox" name="city" />';
}
else // show select box
{
?>
<select name="city">
<option>Select City</option>
<?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
<option value><?php echo $row['city']?></option>

<?php } ?>
</select>
<?php
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Could you please upvote and select my answer as correct answer plz?

Answer (score 0):

Your `findstate.php` becomes this

```
<?php
include('config.php');
$country=intval($_GET['country']);
$query="SELECT id,statename FROM state WHERE countryid='$country'";
$result=mysqli_query($query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==0):?>
  <input type="text" name="state" value="" />
<? endif; ?>

<select name="state" onchange="getCity(<?=$country ?>,this.value)">
   <option>Select State</option>
   <?php while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)): ?>
     <option value=<?= $row['id']?>><?= $row['statename']?></option>
   <?php endwhile; ?>
</select>
```

Similarly change your `findcity.php` aswell.

**Suggestions**

Never use `mysql*` anymore use `mysqli*` or `PDO` as `mysql*` is depricated. [Link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php)